# Box2D collision detection fails after firing a lot of bullets

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, box2d

I am working on a physics game and encountered a strange bug: sometimes, after firing a lot of bullets, collision detection starts to fail.

As can be seen in the following GIF, the collision works only on half the platform, which is very strange. Also, the Box2D debug renderer is enabled and it can also be seen that the platform is a single body.

[image: Bug]

Here is how I get this bug to happen, as it only happens only after firing lots of bullets (in the beginning everything works fine):

[image: Replicate]

**Notes:**
- the bullet has the `bullet` field set to `true`
- I set the player's `bullet` field to `true`, did not make a difference
- the player is 1 meter by 1 meter
- the player and the bullets are `DynamicBodies` and the platforms are `StaticBodies`
- the map is near to (0, 0), though it goes a bit in the negatives (-1.5), I doubt it matters
- the `categoryBits` and `maskBits` are correct (the collision should happen, and it does happen, but glitches)
- after the bullets disappear, the number of bodies is the same as when the game starts (so they are actually destroyed)
- the `World`'s gravity is (0, -25f)
- the game runs at 60fps

Here is the Box2D timestep code, similar to the stepping code from the [libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#stepping-the-simulation):

```
companion object {
    private const val TIME_STEP = 1f / 300f
    private const val VELOCITY_ITERATIONS = 6
    private const val POSITION_ITERATIONS = 2
}

private var accumulator = 0f

override fun update(deltaTime: Float) {
    accumulator += Math.min(deltaTime, 0.25f)
    while (accumulator >= TIME_STEP) {
        world.step(TIME_STEP, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS)
        accumulator -= TIME_STEP
    }
}
```

**I tried changing:**
- `TIME_STEP` to a lower value, like 1/60f
- `VELOCITY_ITERATIONS` a bit higher, to 8
- `POSITION_ITERATIONS` a bit higher, to 6
- `VELOCITY_ITERATIONS` and `POSITION_ITERATIONS` to 100
and there was no (obvious) difference.

**Concern:**
The bugged platform seems to start behaving like a bullet (it doesn't collide with other bullets or with the player), at least halfway. So could its `categoryBits` and `maskBits` be changed on-the-fly, after a lot of `world.createBody()` and `world.destroyBody()`, maybe due to pooling?

So what should I try for the collision not to fail in this case?

Comment: You are not doing anything with bullet position other than applying a force to the bullets when you fire them?

Comment: Also, are you using a contact listener, or are you iterating and checking contacts?

Comment: @Laurence No, I am not setting the bullet's (or player's, for that matter) position manually, I only apply a force when I fire them. And yes, I am using a `ContactListener`, overriding the `beginContact(contact: Contact)` function.

Comment: It looks like it is some section of the wall that remains "broken". In your collision listener, your bullet and wall fixtures will not always be the same arguments. You are definitely destroying or manipulating the bullet in your collisions?

Comment: @Laurence If you are asking if I check whether the bodies from the contact are a platform and a bullet, yes, I am checking. I keep the entity that owns that body in its `userData` and check if it `is Platform` or `is Bullet`. And yes, I am definitely destroying the bullet after it collides with a platform (the `world.bodyCount` behaves correctly).

Comment: Cool  ya just ruling things out. Just to let you know I have built games which shoot constant streams of bullets that bounced, so this is not a box2d issue.

Comment: Can you turn your own rendering off, just the box2d debug?

Comment: But the fact that your player and bullets pass through wall. You have done something to the walls physics.

Comment: @Laurence [Here](https://i.imgur.com/eDEW3UM.mp4) is how it looks only with the Box2D debug rendering (pretty much the same). I guess the problem is in my code, but I don't really know what would cause Box2D to behave in this way, for collision to work only in half the platform. What do you mean by doing something to the walls physics? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Wow. Too weird. Happy to run it and try dig into it if you post a bigger snippet?

Comment: @Laurence Well the game's [open-source](https://github.com/Luca1152/gravity-box), if you are willing to go through it, as there isn't really one snippet I can post.

Comment: been trying to recreate on desktop...  no luck so far. Are you only seeing the bug on android?

Comment: @Laurence No. But it seems to happen more often at level #25 (after spamming bullets) for some reason, so you could try that.

Comment: @Laurence I managed to fix it! I posted my answer, but as I mentioned there, I am not really sure why I need to do that in order for it to work.

Comment: Ah dude. Cool. :) I did checkout and change the level id to 25. Got the bug to appear once, but forgot to run in debug... but ya, cool. I still find it really weird that half of a fixture was effected.

Comment: Nice little game as well btw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it.

The solution I found was to loop through every entity that has a body and call `refilter()`, which seems to fix it:

```
engine.getEntitiesFor(Family.one(BodyComponent::class.java).get()).forEach {
    it.body.body.fixtureList.first().refilter()
}
```

In the future, I could call `refilter()` only when needed (if I can determine when I have to call it) instead of calling it every frame, but it works for now.

It looks like you should call `refilter()` after you change the `filterData` of a body (changing its `categoryBits` or `maskBits`) outside the `FixtureDef`, but I don't seem to be doing that (or maybe I am missing something), so it is a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you for coming back with the answer to your own question. Too many on SO don't. This solved the problem I have been having for months in my game. I am so glad I could finally fix it.

Comment: No problem! It really was a frustrating problem to solve (where to even start, right?), that's why I especially wanted to come back with my solution.